# Highcharts - Reset the chart after clicking bootstrap tabs without changing the chart values

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, bootstrap-tabs

I am using Highcharts with Bootstrap.

How can I redraw the chart each time on clicking on tabs?

Please find the Demo below...

**http://jsfiddle.net/et7Lvg6c/**

```js
$(function () {
  // Everything in common between the charts
  var commonOptions = {
    colors: ['#f68936', '#70ba47', '#33b5e6', '#fd8f40', '#e7ca60', '#40abaf', '#f6f7f8', '#e9e9eb'],
    chart: {
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto Light',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fontSize: '12px',
        color: '#585858',
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: null
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      title: {
        style: {
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          color: "#bbb",
        }
      },
      labels: {
        style:{ color: '#bbb' },
      },
      lineWidth: 1,
      tickLength: 0,
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        style: {
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          color: "#bbb",
        }
      },
      offset:-6,
      labels: {
        style:{ color: '#bbb' },
        //format:'{value}K',
      },
      tickInterval: 100,
      lineWidth: 1,
      gridLineDashStyle: 'dash',
    },
    series: [{
      //backgroundColor: "rgba(0 ,0, 0, 1)",
    }],

    // Area Chart
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        fillOpacity: 0.1
      },
      area: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        marker: {
          lineWidth: 2,
          symbol: 'circle',
          fillColor: 'white',
          radius:3,
        },
        legend: {
          radius: 2,
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      shared: true,
      backgroundColor: '#5f5f5f',
      borderWidth: 0,
      style: {
        padding:10,
        color: '#fefefe',
      }
    },
    legend: {
      itemStyle: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto Light',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fontSize: '12',
        color: '#666666',
      },
      marker: {
        symbol: 'square',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        radius: '4',
      },
      symbolHeight: 6,
      symbolWidth: 6,
    },
  };

  // -----------------------------------------------------
  $('.areaChartTwoWay').each(function() {
    $(this).highcharts(Highcharts.merge(commonOptions, {
      chart: { type: 'area' },
      xAxis: {
        title: { text: 'Date', },
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          day: '%eth %b'
        },
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: { text: 'Count', },
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Forwards',
        color: '#f68936',
        marker: { lineColor: '#f68936', fillColor: 'white', },
        data: [185, 290, 198, 220, 180, 140, 220, 335, 197, 240],
        legendIndex:1,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 11),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
      }, {
        name: 'Unique opens',
        color: '#70ba47',
        marker: { lineColor: '#70ba47', fillColor: 'white', },
        data: [90, 95, 98, 80, 70, 68, 85, 71, 64, 90],
        legendIndex:0,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 11),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
      }]
    }))

  });

  // -----------------------------------------------------
  $('.areaChartOneWay').each(function() {
    $(this).highcharts(Highcharts.merge(commonOptions, {
      chart: { type: 'area' },
      xAxis: {
        title: { text: 'Date', },
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          day: '%eth %b'
        },
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: { text: 'Count', },
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Forwards',
        color: '#f68936',
        marker: { lineColor: '#f68936', fillColor: 'white', },
        data: [215, 325, 235, 380],
        legendIndex:1,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 11),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
      }, {
        name: 'Unique opens',
        color: '#70ba47',
        marker: { lineColor: '#70ba47', fillColor: 'white', },
        data: [15,53,42,38],
        legendIndex:0,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 11),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
      }]
    }))

  });

  $('.highcharts-grid > path:last-child').remove();
  $('.highcharts-markers > path:last-child').remove();

});


jQuery(document).on( 'shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
  jQuery( ".newChart" ).each(function() {
    var chart = jQuery(this).highcharts();
    chart.reflow();
  });
})
```

```css
body{margin:20px;}
.tab-content{padding-top:30px;border:1px solid #ddd;border-top:none;}
.nav{padding-left:50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


<div class="clearfix">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#chart1" aria-controls="chart1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Chart 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#chart2" aria-controls="chart2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Chart 2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="chart1">
      <div class="areaChartTwoWay newChart" style="height: 250px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="chart2">
      <div class="areaChartOneWay newChart" style="height: 250px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just use chart.redraw() on tab click, as you do with chart.reflow()?http://jsfiddle.net/et7Lvg6c/1/

Comment: **@morganfree**, already tried that and somehow it is now working though... :(

Comment: try hide chart series and show them after small interval will feel like re drawing.

for(var i = 0 ; i<chart.series.length ;  i++){
chart.series[i].hide();
}
setTimeout(function(){
for(var i = 0 ; i<chart.series.length ;  i++){
    chart.series[i].show();
}
},300);